# O que é "scoped address zone" no IPv6?

Tags: ip, redes, ipv6

Estava vendo a biblioteca do *net* do Golang, [até que achei o tipo IPAddr](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPAddr) que é exatamente:

```
type IPAddr struct {
        IP   IP
        Zone string // IPv6 scoped addressing zone
}
```

O que me chamou a atenção é esse "Zone", que se refere à "IPv6 scoped addressing zone".

O que seria isto e qual a finalidade?

Comment: _Acredito que isto seja independente do Golang, por isso não inclui a tag do Go._

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4007#page-4